# Change the default style of a CSS class

Tags: html, css, typescript, ionic-framework, mapbox

I am using a mapbox api to generate a map. I'm trying to make `width` and `height` equal to 100%, but the class `mapboxgl-canvas` has a default value, and I don't know how to overwrite it.

```html
<canvas class="mapboxgl-canvas" tabindex="0" aria-label="Map" width="400" height="300" style="position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 300px;"></canvas>
```

It has a height of 300px and a width of 400px.

**CSS:**

```
#map, .mapboxgl-canvas{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Tab 2
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

This is **typescript** that loads the map from mapbox:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  environment
} from '../../environments/environment.prod';
import * as Mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
@Component({

  selector: 'app-tab2',

  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}
  title = 'view';
  map: Mapboxgl.Map;
  ngOnInit() {
    (Mapboxgl as any).accessToken = environment.mapboxKey;
    this.map = new Mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map', // container id
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [-74.810913, 10.985246], // LNG, LAT
      zoom: 14 // starting zoom
    });

    // Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
    this.map.addControl(new Mapboxgl.NavigationControl());


  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `width` & `height` HTML & CSS attributes from the canvas?

Comment: I don't know how to overwrite canvas styles

Comment: Not **overwriting** just removing it from the HTML or does it get loaded in via. JS?

Comment: It is a map api that is loaded in the js

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include the JS?